# AWS Glue crawler: different schema for input data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a subfolder in a S3 bucket to store CSV files. These CSV files all contain data from one specific data source. The data source provides a new CSV file monthly. I have about 4 years worth of data.

At some point (~2 years ago) the data source decided to change the format of the data. The schema of the CSV changed (some columns were removed). The data is still more or less the same, and everything I want is still there.

I want to use a crawler to register both schemas, preferably in the same table. Ideally, I would like it to recognize the two versions of the schema.

How should I do that?

## What I tried

- I uploaded all the files in the subfolder and run a crawler with "Create a single schema for each S3 path" enabled.

Result: I got one table with both schemas merged: one big schema with all the columns from both formats

- I uploaded all the files in the subfolder and run a crawler with "Create a single schema for each S3 path" disabled.

Result: I got two tables with the two distinct schemas

## Why I need this

The two different schemas need to be processed differently. I'm writing a Python shell job to process the files. My idea was to use the catalog to pull the two different versions of the schema, and trigger different treatments for each file depending on the schema of the file.

Comment: What solution did you end up implementing for your scenario here?

Comment: I'd be interested in the solution as well...